# Shopify: Adding array of images to Product Variant Metafield using REST API

Tags: c#, rest, shopify, shopify-api

I want to achieve following:

> "I am getting a url for a pdf file from user. I am supposed to convert that PDF file to list of JPEG images. Then, I am supposed to store all those JPEG images to the metafield under Product Variant of Shopify."

I am done with PDF file to list of JPEG images conversion part. I am getting the list of images in following both formats:

1. `List<System.Drawing.Image>`
2. `List<string>` (Images converted to String with Base64).

I have created a Metafield named 'concept_list' under Product Variant. It is of type 'List of files'.

So, now I am having trouble adding list of images which I have using REST API calls. I can easily add images to 'Product Images' or 'Product Variant Images' giving attachment in the form of string with base 64. But, I think, I can not use similar attachment while adding image files to Product Variant Metafield. **If you know any way with which I can achieve this using attachment in the form of string with base 64, please let me know in the answer.**